# SQL Query for total time water pump on between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a water pump that the run state is stored in a mssql database every 10 seconds along with the time of day. The pump cycles often through out the day. How do I query for the total time the pump was on during the day?

Comment: Need a little more information, like table structure and how often you're looking to query the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pump WHERE state = on
```

Take the result, and multiply by 10 to get time on in seconds?

As mentioned in the comments, if you also select the date and `GROUP BY` date you can get counts per day.

Comment: Well this would give him the total count, not per day.  you would need to do some Grouping

Answer (score 1):

Group by day, count the number of records, and multiply by 10:

```
select 
   year = datepart(y,datefield)
,  dayofyear = datepart(dy,datefield)
,  minuteson = count(*)*10
from pump
where state = 'on'
group by datepart(y,datefield), datepart(dy,datefield)
```